# Run unittest from a Python program via a command-line option

Tags: python, unit-testing

Here is my set up -

```
project/
    __init__.py
    prog.py
    test/
        __init__.py
        test_prog.py
```

I would like to be able to run my unit tests by calling a command-line option in *prog.py*. This way, when I deploy my project, I can deploy the ability to run the unit tests at any time.

```
python prog.py --unittest
```

What do I need in *prog.py*, or the rest of my project for this to work?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Perhaps [this](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#load-tests-protocol) is what you're looking for. Implement a `load_tests` function in `test_prog.py` and use the following code in `prog.py` to load and run the tests:

```
import unittest
import test.test_prog
suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromModule(test.test_prog)
unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)
```

Answer (score 82):

The Python `unittest` module contains its own [test discovery](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#test-discovery) function, which you can run from the command line:

```
$ python -m unittest discover
```

To run this command from within your module, you can use the `subprocess` module:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import subprocess

# ...
# the rest of your module's code
# ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if '--unittest' in sys.argv:
        subprocess.call([sys.executable, '-m', 'unittest', 'discover'])
```

If your module has other command-line options you probably want to look into [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) for more advanced options.

Answer (score 13):

You must make sure that you consistently follow some naming conventions (which you seem to be doing):

1. All tests are named with the same prefix (`test_` is the norm), followed by the name of the module you wish to test.

   `prog.py` => `test_prog.py`
2. Tests reside in `test/` directory.

Then you can do something like this:

### prog.py

```
import sys
...
... do module stuff here...
...

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Check if we want to run the tests for this file
    if "--unittest" in sys.argv:
        import unittest

        test_filename = 'test_' + __file__
        test_directory = 'test'

        suite = unittest.TestLoader().discover(test_directory, pattern=test_filename)
        unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

---

What we are doing, is:

- Checking the command arguments to see if `--unittest` is present (since that's the only time you want to run the tests).
- If it is, then we create the `test_prog.py` - following the naming conventions we have set.
- Then we pass that to the `TestLoader().discover` function.

  [discover(...)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestLoader.discover) starts at the specified directory and finds all test modules (recursing into subdirectories ) that match the pattern provided.

  In our case, it will look inside the `test/` directory for any module named `test_prog.py`. When it does, it loads it and creates a TestSuite with the TestCases that we want to run.
- Lastly, we manually test `unittest` to run the `suite` obtained in the previous step.

---

Normally, `unittest` will do all of this for us in the background, but since we are trying to run a specific test module, we have to tell exactly how and where to get it from.

Also, note that you will have to do this for **every** file where you want to do this at.

Answer (score 1):

I just removed the `.idea` hidden directory under the project in the file system.

I restarted [PyCharm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyCharm), reopened the project, and this issue was resolved.

Comment: that actually worked for me.