# Creating Unittest class inside function not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

In the attached script why 0 testcases are running

```
import unittest


def smg():
    def add(x, y):
        return x + y

    class SimpleTest(unittest.TestCase):
        def testadd1(self):
            self.assertEquals(add(4, 5), 9)
        

        if __name__ == '__main__':
            unittest.main()

smg()
```

Gives

```
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s
```

What can be done to fix it kindly assist

Comment: Unittest cannot discover the test class within a function, move it out of `smg()`. Do you need it inside a function for a particular reason?

Comment: In my project i need to call unitest function only when some action is performed so for this I need o put this inside function

Comment: Test discovery parses the *text* of your script; it does not look for runtime effects.

Comment: If you want to do something like this, you will have to write your own code to gather the tests and run them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be interested with [unittest.TextTestRunner](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TextTestRunner):

> A basic test runner implementation that outputs results to a stream.

Sample [usage](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#organizing-test-code):

> However, should you want to customize the building of your test suite, you can do it yourself:
>
> ```py
> def suite():
>     suite = unittest.TestSuite()
>     suite.addTest(WidgetTestCase('test_default_widget_size'))
>     suite.addTest(WidgetTestCase('test_widget_resize'))
>     return suite
>
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>     runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
>     runner.run(suite())
> ```

Sample run for your case.

**src.py**

```
def add(x, y):
    print("Add", x, y)
    return x + y
```

**test_src.py**

```
import unittest

from src import add


class SimpleTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def testadd1(self):
        self.assertEqual(add(4, 5), 9)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Running tests is as how it's done normally

```
$ python test_src.py  # Using unittest
Add 4 5
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
$ pytest -q  # Using pytest
.                                                                                                                                                                                                   
1 passed in 0.06s
```

Now if you want to manually call it via function.

**run_tests.py**

```
import unittest

import test_src


def suite():
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite.addTest(test_src.SimpleTest('testadd1'))
    return suite


def run():
    runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
    runner.run(suite())

# run()  # Uncomment if you want to try to run it as a script e.g. <python run_tests.py>
```

You can now just import the file and call `run()` whenever you need:

```
$ python3
>>> import run_tests
>>> run_tests.run()
Add 4 5
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take out the code inside of `smg` function and then run tests from your command-line with `python -m unittest <Your Filename>.py`.

Your code will look like this:

```py
import unittest


def add(x, y):
    return x + y


class SimpleTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def testadd1(self):
        self.assertEquals(add(4, 5), 9)
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Also you may get a deprecation warning for `assertEquals`. You might want to change it to `assertEqual` instead.

Comment: thanks Salek for the reply , I am aware this method works  , I my project i need to call unitest function only when some action is performed so for this I need o put this inside function

Comment: @Lakpa Then you might want to use subprocess module in your code as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16866179/9134517). But still you have to remove the redundant smg function for unittest in order to work.